# Não consigo atualizar meu app na google play?

Tags: java, android, android-studio, google-play

sei que é necessário alterar o número da versão, porém quando faço a alteração e tento gerar um apk dá erro e me mostra uma mensagem...

Error:Versão XML "2.0" não suportada; somente XML 1.0 é suportada.

Comment: Everton, se a [resposta do Wakim](http://pt.stackoverflow.com/a/51571/6454) te ajudou, vote nela, se ela é a certa, marque-a como *aceita*, dê uma olhada aqui: http://meta.pt.stackoverflow.com/a/1079/6454

Answer (score 17, accepted):

Acredito que você tenha alterado isso:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
```

Para isso:

```
<?xml version="2.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
```

Não está correto, porque essa é a versão do XML que é usado no **AndroidManifest**. É necessário manter como está.

---

Para incrementar a versão do seu aplicativo você precisa definir e modificar duas propriedades, mas a forma como isso é feito depende de como está fazendo o *build* do aplicativo.

As duas propriedades que dizem a versão do seu aplicativo são `android:versionCode` e `android:versionName`.

## VersionCode

O *VersionCode* é um inteiro que representa a versão do código do seu aplicativo, relativo a outras versões. Você pode até programaticamente gerar esse valor, ele é apenas um número que diz quando um aplicativo é mais recente que outro. Ele não tem relação com a versão que o usuário vê.

Ele é usado apenas pelo *Google Play* e outras lojas, para saber que houve uma atualização no **apk** que você enviou, assim fazendo a distribuição.

Você pode usar a regra que quiser, até tendo espaços entre versões. Por experiência própria eu sempre incremento em 1 a cada atualização. Se você subir uma versão já usada, o *Google Play* irá rejeitar seu *upload*.

## VersionName

O *VersionName* é uma `String` que representa a versão do *release* do seu aplicativo. Você pode usar a notação comum de `<major>.<minor>.<point>` (e.g: 2.0.1) ou qualquer outra forma que achar conveniente. Por ser uma `String` você seguir a ordem que quiser, que não faz diferença (O único problema é confundir o usuário).

Essa é a versão que o usuário de fato observa nas lojas.

---

Como eu citei, a configuração vai depender de como você faz o *build* do seu apk.

## Se você usa o ADT

Apenas modifique os atributos `android:versionCode` e `android:versionName` na sua tag `manifest`:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    package="com.example.package.name"
    android:versionCode="2" <!-- Valor que as lojas usam para identificar que houve uma atualizacao -->
    android:versionName="1.1"> <!-- Valor que aparece para o usuario -->

    <application android:icon="@drawable/icon" android:label="@string/app_name">
    ...
    </application>
</manifest>
```

## Se você usa o Gradle

Com o Gradle, você pode configurar o `versionCode` e `versionName` no `build.gradle`, mas lembre-se que ele sempre sobreescreverá o valor da tag `manifest`. Caso contrário é o valor da tag `manifest` que prevalecerá.

Exemplo de configuração:

```
apply plugin: 'com.android.application'

android {
    compileSdkVersion 19
    buildToolsVersion "19.0.0"

    defaultConfig {
        minSdkVersion 8
        targetSdkVersion 19
        versionCode 1        # Valor que as lojas usam para identificar que houve uma atualizacao
        versionName "1.0"    # Valor que aparece para o usuario
    }
    buildTypes {
        release {
            minifyEnabled true
            proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-android.txt'), 'proguard-rules.txt'
        }
    }
}
```

Vale a pena olhar as referências para um melhor entendimento.

Referências:

- http://developer.android.com/tools/publishing/versioning.html
- http://developer.android.com/tools/building/configuring-gradle.html

Comment: Consegui, muito obrigado!! @Wakim